# Properties.Resources.XXXX Namespace or Module not Defined

Tags: f#

I'm trying to read in the text (as a `string`) of an XML file from my `Resources`. The XML file is named `MyXMLResourceFile.resx`.

I tried using the C# way using

```
let myFile : string = Properties.Resources.MyXMLResourceFile
```

but it is giving me the error (under `Properties`):

```
The namespace or module 'Properties' is not defined.
```

I'm assuming I'm missing an `open` but have no idea what it would be.

Sorry, I'm still pretty new to F# coming from VB.

**Additional information:**

I made the `resx` file myself per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2691785/632495) I then looked to see how others accessed it. In C# they did Properties.Resources.XXXX [per this project](https://github.com/OnorioCatenacci/ExtendedSearch/blob/master/ExtendedSearch/ExtendedSearch.fs) I saw you could use `ResourceManager` but didn't see any method to read the whole file directly into a `string`.

Comment: Could you please clarify what kind of application are you creating (ASP.NET, WPF, or something else?) and how did you create it (using some template?)

Comment: I'm creating a library. I'm not using a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The namespace or module 'Properties' is not defined.
```

That's because the namespace Properties is not defined. You probably brought the resx file from another project. Open the associated .Designer file, if it doesn't appear in the F# project, open it up in the original project. You will see a namespace with and a bunch of C# code, assuming the original project was in C#. The namespace of this file has to be the same namespace of the project where you are trying to call it.

But, since this is C# code, it won't run on a F# project. You have two choices: use a code generator to generate the associated .Designer class in F# code with the Properties namespace, (I don't know if such generator exists); or pre-compile the resx in the original project and reference it as a dll from your F# project, then you can access it with ResourceManager.

Comment: See "Additional Information" in my comment. I actually think I might have thought of a way to do it - make the XML equal to a variable then grab the variable, maybe? I don't know if that would work since it uses new lines.

Comment: You second link shows you how to do it with ResourceManager. Isn't that what you want? Or do you want to read the actual XML into a string, and not the values?

Comment: Yes, I need to read it into a string and not the values. I'll be using FSharp.Data to read the values of a dynamic XML. I just need the embedded XML as a template for FSharp.Data. http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html

Comment: If you want to read the xml as a string, wouldn't File.ReadAllText solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping to embed the file. I suppose I don't need to though - although it would be preferable. I didn't realize it would be so difficult to embed.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2820420/9776 ? Seems to be what you need, it's in C#, but there's no reason why it shouldn't work in F#.

Comment: That looks like it. I'll be out of town for over a week without my computer so I'll look at it then. I'll let you know how it works when I get back and mark you correct if it does. Thanks for your help!