# F#: How to embed resources in a dll?

Tags: .net, f#

I'm writing an F# module for a C# application and resources embedded in the DLL are used quite a bit.

The F# project doesn't allow me to add Resources.

Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: The answers to this question might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689446/how-to-manage-resources-in-an-f-project